# I need to upgrade Karma and Jasmine versions

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I need to upgrade **Karma** and **Jasmine** versions but I don't know if I have to update all of these packages or not:

```
"jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
"jasmine-marbles": "0.8.3",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
"karma": "^6.3.2",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-coverage": "^2.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
"karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
```

I started with upgrading **Jasmine** to `4.6.0` but nothing changed I only found the package added to `package.json`